# JavaFX TableView/Column Null pointer exception

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, tableview, scenebuilder

I am having trouble with Null pointers when trying to initiate Table population.
I have my object from class called `Komponenta` which data I put in `ObservableList` and then try to show it in a `TableView`. I've tried this time to work with multiple fxml screens and for some reason it doesn't work with more than 1 `.fxml`. `test` is a method that I call when a button is pressed on `main.fxml` so it loads a new one.

MainController.java

```
public ObservableList<Komponenta> komponente = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Komponenta("Neki Tip", "Neki Proizvodac","Neki opis", 5));
@FXML
private TableView<Komponenta> Tablica;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Komponenta,String> Tip;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Komponenta,String> Proizvodac;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Komponenta,String> Karakteristika;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Komponenta,Integer> Komada;
@FXML
private void test(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    Node node=(Node) event.getSource();
    Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
    Parent root = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ElKomponenta.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();       
}
@FXML
private void initialize() throws Exception  {
    System.out.println(komponente.get(0).getKomada());
    Tip.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Komponenta, String>("tip"));
    Proizvodac.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Komponenta, String>("proizvodac"));
    Karakteristika.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Komponenta, String>("karakteristika"));
    Komada.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Komponenta, Integer>("komada"));
    Tablica.setItems(komponente);
}
```

ElKomponenta.fxml

```xml
<TableView fx:id="Tablica" prefHeight="603.0" prefWidth="889.0">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="Tip" prefWidth="177.0" text="Tip" />
    <TableColumn fx:id="Proizvodac" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="207.0" text="Proizvođač" />
      <TableColumn fx:id="Karakteristika" prefWidth="326.0" text="Karakteristike" />
      <TableColumn fx:id="Komada" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="178.0" text="Komada" />
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:62)
... 27 more
```

Which is the line that first starts to `setCellValueFactory`.

Also if needed, Komponenta.java

```
public class Komponenta {

    private String proizvodac;
    private String tip;
    private String karakteristika;
    private Integer komada;

    public Komponenta(String a, String b, String c, Integer d){
        this.tip = a;
        this.proizvodac = b;
        this.karakteristika = c;
        this.komada = d;
    }

    public String getProizvodac() {
        return proizvodac;
    }

    public void setProizvodac(String proizvodac) {
        this.proizvodac = proizvodac;
    }

    public String getTip() {
        return tip;
    }

    public void setTip(String tip) {
        this.tip = tip;
    }

    public String getKarakteristika() {
        return karakteristika;
    }

    public void setKarakteristika(String karakteristika) {
        this.karakteristika = karakteristika;
    }

    public Integer getKomada() {
        return komada;
    }

    public void setKomada(Integer komada) {
        this.komada = komada;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main.fxml` doesn't seem to contain a `TableColumn` with `fx:id` `Tip`, but seems to use the same controller class. Since `initialize` is called at the end of **every** invocation of a `FXMLLoader.load` method that uses the controller instance, loading of `main.fxml` results in the `NullPointerException`.

Use different controller classes for both `fxml`s instead: The one for `main.fxml` should contain the button action handler and the one for `ElKomponenta.fxml` should contain the `TableView` related stuff.